# How to call a WCF .net webservice by using grails

Tags: .net, wcf, grails, web-services, call

By using grails I have to consume WCF WebService.I was trying but could not.If someone could just tell me the steps to call a webservice by using grails.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using GroovyWS? http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS